# Questions about basis of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a few questions about basis and would appreciate any help. And I'm not looking for answers that just restate theorems, I need simple explanation that will help me understand this topic. Thank you.

1) Explain how to find a basis in span {v1 , . . . , vm}

2) Explain how to complete a linearly independent collection of vectors
v1 , . . . , vk to a basis of Rn.

3) If a subspace S of Rn has dimension k, explain how to decide
whether vectors v1 , . . . , vk in S form a basis.

4) Explain how to compute coordinates of a vector x in a given basis
B = fv1 , . . . , vkg.

Comment: For 1) Start with $v_1$. If it is non-zero, put it into your basis set. If it is zero, throw it away and proceed with $v_2$. Let us assume that $v_1\neq 0$. Then it is in the basis set now. If $v_2$ and $v_1$ are linearly independent, put also $v_2$ in your basis set. If they are not, throw $v_2$ away. You further proceed in this way. When you have reached $v_k$, see whether the vectors in the basis set and $v_k$ are linearly independent. If so, put $v_k$ in there, if not throw $v_k$ away.

Comment: Thank you @amsmath it makes so much sense! But you didn't say anything about span or spanning. Could you explain to me how they relate to basis, because I'm asking how to find a basis in span

Comment: In the last step you decide about $v_m$ - whether to put it into your basis set or to throw it away. When you are done with this, your basis set contains a basis for the span of the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$. It's that simple.

Comment: It's like this. The span of the $v_k$'s is by definition spanned by $v_1,\ldots,v_m$. But there might be vectors that you can kick out of this set such that the span of the remaining vectors is the same as before. For example, if you have $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(2,2)$. Then you can throw away, e.g., $(2,2)$ and the span remains the same.

Comment: It's like when I tell you that I will go out for biking. And then I tell you that I will use my bike. Oh, really??? Well, this second information is redundant. And so are the vectors that you can kick out. They don't change the span.

Comment: Love your example XD Thank you for taking the time to write all this, greatly appreciate it. And yes, now I see it as redundant too. So basically the answer to my first question would be, find the basis by kicking out redundant vectors.

Comment: Please read the following carefully. It is supposed to give you a good picture of linear algebra: Vectors are like information. If you have a couple of vectors, you have bits of information. Now you can combine those bits of information (linear combinations). Great, that gives you even more information - actually much more. The span of the vectors is the entirety of information that you can squeeze out of the information bits (the vectors) by combining them.

Comment: However, there might be bits of information that follow from combining the others (like: $v_1 =$"outside it's raining, $v_2=$"kids are playing football", $v_3=$"The ball is wet"). This is redundant information that you better forget about since it might confuse you. The entirety of information remains. In the end, when there is no redundancy anymore, you have a basis. So, a basis is a minimal set of information bits that still gives you all the information that you had before. And now I go to bed.